# multi field mapping elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to map a multi field in elasticsearch

- 1st field  - 'in' should contain all the indexed column,
- 2nd field - 'orig' should contain the text as-is.

For example:

```
    "findings": {
       "type": "multi_field",
       "fields": {
          "in": {
             "type": "string"
          },
          "orig": {
             "type": "string",
             "index":"not_analyzed"
          }
       }
```

Once I create this and query this is how it looks.

When index = 'no' does it mean the field will never be indexed at all?

```
  "findings": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "no",
                  "fields": {
                     "in": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "orig": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"index" : "no"` has got different meaning for different types. Since `findings` field in your question is `String` it has following meaning according to `elasticsearch documentation`.

> no means that it won’t be searchable at all (as an individual field; it may still be included in _all). Setting to no disables include_in_all.

you can not directly search for the field `findings` as it has got `index: no` while you can search it using `findings.in` or `findings.orig`

You can study more about `index` property [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-core-types.html#string)

Answer (score 2):

Multi_fields have been removed from elasticsearch for long.

Instead, any of the core field types (excluding object and nested) now accept a fields parameter, as also shown in OP's second example.

However, When you specify `fields` inside any other field, it simply means copying the content to a different field and apply a different set of analyzers for querying on the same content.

So when you specify `index=no` , the field is not indexed as such and hence is not searchable but the inner fields have properties of their own.

You may also use `copy_to` to copy the content to other fields and specify the different analyzers there but then there is no 'explicit' relationship between the two fields which is pretty explicit in multi_fields as new fields are accessed as `'findings.in'` or `'findings.orig'`

Comment: thanks..What are you referring as OP's second example?

Comment: you have used "type": "multi_field" in first mapping whereas "type":"string" in your second mapping. Second mapping was being referred as 2nd example